# Service will not inject into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-services, angularjs-factory

I've made a handful of Angular applications in the past, but have never really made use of modules.  I'm creating an Ionic app right now (which uses Angular) and for some reason I cannot get my services to inject into the controllers.

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('myapp.controllers', [])
.controller('StreamCtrl', ['$scope', 'StreamService',
function($scope, StreamService) {
    $scope.playlists = [1,2,3,4];
}]);
```

**services.js**

```
angular.module('myapp.services', [])
.factory('StreamService', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var self = {
        'fetching' : false,
        'streamItems' : []
    };
    return self;
]);
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ionic',
                        'myapp.services',
                        'myapp.controllers',
                        'ngCordova',
                        'LocalStorageModule'])
// And lots of other code that isn't needed for this question.
```

So when I try and load the `StreamCtrl` I end up getting the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <-StreamService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/unpr?p0=<ion-nav-view name="menuContent" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios">copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20StreamService
at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:7888:12)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11806:19
at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11953:39)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11811:45
at getService (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11953:39)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11985:13)
at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11847:37)
at Object.invoke (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11994:17)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11812:37
at getService (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11953:39)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11116/) ,

You are treating service as if it was a controller, never inject a `$scope` into service, its not there

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['myapp.services','myapp.controllers']);

angular.module('myapp.controllers', [])
.controller('StreamCtrl', ['$scope', 'StreamService',
function($scope, StreamService) {
    $scope.playlists = [1,2,3,4];
}]);

angular.module('myapp.services', []).factory('StreamService',  function() {
    var self = {
        'fetching' : false,
        'streamItems' : []
    };
    return self;}
);
```

Comment: Good call.  Was completely on auto-pilot writing that and forgot to remove the the $scope dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Your error clearly says there is problem inside `StreamService` factory.

You could never inject `$scope` inside `factory`. Removing `$scope` dependency will solve your issue.

Factory basically used to expose singleton methods, common and sharable data. Usually we write any service call or method which can be accessible by any module who inject it using its dependancy.

**Factory**

```
angular.module('myapp.services', [])
.factory('StreamService', [function() {
    var self = {
        'fetching': false,
        'streamItems': []
    };
    return self;
}]);
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11117/).

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: downvoter could i know what is the reason for downvote?

Comment: I dont know who downvoted, but maybe because your answer has a wrong syntax, there shouldnt be a function inside array within service

Comment: @NaeemShaikh  No that is ok..that is for strict-di

Comment: @JackSlingerland I also did the same..why mine answer wont helped

Comment: I found out .. edited your answer.. @downvoter please remove the downvote

Comment: dont worry.. its just that my answer got accepted and your didnt. your answer is helpful as well. :) i upvoted

Comment: @pankajparkar Yours was helpful, but naeem-shaikh came first.  Upvoted, and thanks for the help.

Comment: @JackSlingerland Now you can clearly see, I gave answer exact 4 minutes earlier than him.. Thanks..